# Adding Java WebView to pure Android NDK application

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I have a pure NDK application, entirely `C++`.

I now need to add access to a `WebView`; Google search and stack-overflow have informed me that I have to do this in `Java`.

How do I go about including `Java` class (derived from `WebView`) into my pure Android NDK application and how do I invoke it?

**Note:** I am not using Eclipse or any other IDE, just `.mk` file etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use JNI and make an upcall from your C++-code to Java. Calling a Java language method from within native code involves the following three steps:

1. Retrieve a class reference
2. Retrieve a method identifier
3. Call the methods

There's a good explaination on how to do this here: [Sun JNI Reference](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniref.html#call)

You need a Java class that can receive this method call, and that can start up an Activity containing a webview. So, you can include and invoke Java from C++, but naturally you still need to implement the Java-class in Java, there's no getting away from that.